# Why do I get two March when looping out month names?

Tags: php

Why do I get two March instead of February then March when running the following code?

```
<?php

  for($i=1; $i<= 12; $i++){

  //MONTH NAME
  $monthName = strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i));

  if($i <= 9){
    $monthNr = "0".$i;
  }
  else{
    $monthNr = $i;
  }

  echo $monthNr . ':' . ucfirst($monthName) ."\n";

  }
?>
```

Output:

```
01:January
02:March
03:March
04:April
05:May
06:June
07:July
08:August
09:September
10:October
11:November
12:December
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of this:

([from the `mktime` function reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php))

> Arguments may be left out in order from right to left; any arguments thus omitted will be set to the current value according to the local date and time.

If the current day is greater than the last day of the specified month, the extra days will extend the resulting timestamp into the next month. In this case today is the 30th, so February 30th becomes March 2nd.

If you add a day to `mktime` you'll get the result you're expecting.

```
$monthName = strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1));
```

Comment: I would mention in your answer the specific reason for a double-March is the 30th of February wraps over into March, and that this wouldn't be reproducible except on days greater than the 28th of the current month :)

Comment: @meagar Good idea, I'll edit. I suppose that means this could also happen to some other months on 31sts, right?

Comment: Yeah, we can see what the results would be if we use `mktime(0, 0, 0, $1, 31)`, and they're what you'd expected: `01:January, 02:March, 03:March, 04:May, 05:May, 06:July, 07:July, 08:August, 09:October, 10:October, 11:December, 12:December`. Quite an annoying bug, since it only happens the last few days of each month.

Comment: @meagar Oh right, we can set the day to 31, of course. I was still thinking about it in the context of this example and I was thinking I'd just test it tomorrow, haha